# cannot read proprety 'pin' of null - react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have this error and cant find why. Everything seems good. The code is working as logic but on the app startup things become worth.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, MapView} from 'react-native';

var weather = React.createClass({
  getInitialstate: function(){
    return {
      pin:[{
        longitude:33.33,
        latitude:33.33
      }]
    };
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <MapView annotations={[this.state.pin]} style={styles.map} onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}>
      </MapView>
    )
  },

  onRegionChangeComplete: function(region){
    this.setState({
      pin:{
        longitude: region.longitude,
        latitude: region.latitude
      }
    });

    // console.log([this.pin]);
  }

});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map:{
    flex:1
  }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('weather', () => weather);
```

Im using mapView and changing the annotations. Please Help !

Comment: You have several bugs, but I guess the one that concerns this questions is that you defined `getInitialstate` not `getInitialState`.

Answer (score 0):

create the state object on constructor of weather class

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
}
```

Comment: That's only true for ES6 classes. As you can see, he is using createClass.